# Getting a "Unit httpd.service failed to load: No such file or directory" error when attempting to run Apache service

Tags: apache

I've setup an Amazon EC2 instance running CentOS7. I logged into the machine using Putty (SSH) and ran the "sudo yum update" command. It installed the updates successfully. I then had to install wget. I then downloaded the XAMPP installer from the following location:

**https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.5.38/xampp-linux-x64-5.5.38-1-installer.run**

I then ran the ./ command to install this .run file. The install appeared to be successful.

Now I'm trying to start the apache service and the mysql service using the "sudo service httpd start" command and it's giving me the following error:

[centos@ip-x-x-x-x ~]$ Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
Failed to start httpd.service: Unit httpd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Any ideas why I'm running into this error? Also, I noticed that if I open the /opt/lampp/apache2/httpd.conf file with VI these are the only lines that are listed:

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
~
~
```

Shouldn't there be more lines in this file? Did I install it incorrectly?

Comment: Check log after a failed startup. `journalctl -xn`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the xampp installer doesn't install the init script, you need to create it yourself

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/3hrmsn/have_systemd_start_xampp/

```
vim /etc/system/systemd/xampp.service
```

Containing

```
[Unit]
Description=XAMPP

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/lampp/lampp start
ExecStop=/opt/lampp/lampp stop
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, to enable on startup

```
systemctl enable xampp.service
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This didn't work so I ended up creating a new instance and installing Amazon Linux on it which seems to work better.